# Android: How to detect an application has been swiped out?

Tags: android

Basically, I'd like to detect that my application has been quit to perform some cleanup.

I read few posts on the subject and if we look at the [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html), there is not clear EXIT event, except when the system itself decides to destroy your application which causes to call `onDestroy()`.
Anyway, I'm surprised that nobody talks about a difference which could be, from my point of view, be considered as *application exit*:

On most devices, when you click on the center button, you put your application in background and in that case, `onStop()` is called.
Then, if you click on the right button or perform a long click on the center button, it depends on the device, you can see your application visible.
In this situation you can swipe your application out and **this is** what I would call `QUIT` your application.

It's clearly the event I would detect.

How?

Comment: Maybe you can create a class that extends Application, in that class you can override the ondestroy method. In order to get your class working you need to registher the class in the manifest

Comment: @willermo can you elaborate please because according to Android documentation, there is no certainty that `onDestroy()` being called in any way, except if the system itself decides it, on low memory situation for example.

Comment: Your QUIT is nothing but onDestroy(). willrmo said correct. Put Log in onDestroy() I will come to know

Comment: @willermo, @Kathi, No, I confirm, `onDestroy()` is not called when we swipe an application out from the visible list of background applications. And it seems no event exists to be informed of this action. Contrarly to iOS AFAIR. I think this feature misses.